# this scope in arrow function prototypes

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, rxjs, arrow-functions

Its my understanding that this doesn't work (this is a contrived example - see the RxJS for what I am actually running):

```
function Foo() {
  this.name = 'Johnny Cash'
}

Foo.prototype.who = () => {
  console.log(this.name) // undefined
};

var foo = new Foo();

foo.who()
```

As `this` doesnt have the correct scope. However [this](https://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/how_do_i/simple_event_emitter.html#) page (last 2 bottom examples) on RxJS docs use it. How are they running this code?

Is the code on the RxJS page incorrect? or do I need to run through some kind of Babel plugin ( I already tried running through babel-require and babel-polyfill with same effect)

Comment: `Foo` and `Emitter` are entirely unrelated in this example. It is possible in any number of ways to make `foo` correspond to `this`, the most straight forward of which is `Emitter.prototype.who.call(foo)`. Beyond this, it's rather unclear what you're asking.

Comment: There's also not a single "arrow function" here.

Comment: Lo.l. My bad. I was trying to contrive an example. Typos fixed

Comment: That sample code does look wrong; maybe it was just a mistake by the author.

Comment: @zerkms well if I run this `this.name` is undefined. So I am assuming this is not in the scope I expect - perhaps thats a better phrasing. Other SO questions similar seem to concur that this is not possible. So why or how is RxJS doing this? I am trying to run their code but cannot even with Babel

Comment: Don't use arrow functions to assign prototype methods as an arrow function's *this* is lexical. In the OP, *this* within *who* will always be the global object. Use a function expression instead so that *this* is set by the call. In a browser, *this.name* will reference *window.name*, so return the window's name (if one has been assigned).

Comment: @SebastianG.Marinescu - yes. How is the example from RxJS supossed to work? I just get undefined errors unless I get rid of the arrow functions and go back to 'standard' function definitions

Comment: @RobG so you are agreeing that the RxJS docs are incorrect yes?

Comment: I'm kinda inclined to close this as a duplicate of [ES6 arrow functions not working on the prototype?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31755186/1048572). If your question is really only about the RxJS docs, I think that's off-topic here and should be a simple bug report

Comment: @Bergi you are probably right. When I saw the code in the docs I questioned my own knowledge so came to SO but yes. A big report is being filed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Examples on that page are broken.

It would be fair to assume it was never run as it is currently posted, since it has the syntax error in the

```
var subcription = emitter.listen('data', data => console.log(`data: ${data}`);
```

line (not paired parentheses).

After it is fixed and run - there are other exceptions about reading properties of `undefined`, which is `this` inside the beforementioned arrow functions.

Comment: Thanks. I suspected as much. Just wanted a confirmation

Comment: @Yashua after a second look I have noticed that I *know* the author and I just sent them a link to this question :-)