# Calculate sum of array of objects by specific property return NaN

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6

Hamburger is complemented by one or more `stuffing` (not less than one).
However, when I use `...stuffing` result is `undefined`.
Help me how to correct this task, so that it counts the cost of all the ingredients.

```js
function Hamburger(size, ...stuffing) {
  this.size = size;
  this.stuffing = stuffing;
  this.topping = [];
}
Hamburger.small = {
  name: 'small',
  price: 10,
  kcal: 200
}
Hamburger.cheese = {
  name: 'cheese',
  price: 4,
  kcal: 10
}
Hamburger.meet = {
  name: 'meet',
  price: 40,
  kcal: 103
}
Hamburger.prototype.calculatePrice = () => {
  let allCost = humb1.size.price + humb1.stuffing.price;
  return `Total burger price: ${allCost}`
}

let humb1 = new Hamburger(Hamburger.small, Hamburger.cheese, Hamburger.meet);
console.log(humb1.calculatePrice());
```

Comment: `stuffing` is an array. It doesn't have a `.price` property. If you want the cost of *all* ingredients, you will have to sum them. Use a loop, or `.reduce()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You can't use arrow function they way you used, you need to use the good old `function` declaration instead (or use es6 [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) syntactic-sugar as well). Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31755263/1918287) to understand why (in your case instead of getting the `Hamburger` object you get the global `window` object).
- Don't use `humb1` on the implementation of `calculatePrice` which is a function that is part of the class prototype while `humb1` is a class instance.
- `stuffing` is an array. You need to work on each item to get the total cost. I used [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) here.

```js
function Hamburger(size, ...stuffing) {
  this.size = size;
  this.stuffing = stuffing;
  this.topping = [];
}
Hamburger.small = {
  name: 'small',
  price: 10,
  kcal: 200
}
Hamburger.cheese = {
  name: 'cheese',
  price: 4,
  kcal: 10
}
Hamburger.meet = {
  name: 'meet',
  price: 40,
  kcal: 103
}
Hamburger.prototype.calculatePrice = function() {
  let totalCost = this.size.price + this.stuffing.reduce((a, c) => a + c.price, 0);
  return `Total burger price: ${totalCost}`;
}

let humb1 = new Hamburger(Hamburger.small, Hamburger.cheese, Hamburger.meet);
console.log(humb1.calculatePrice());
```