# Function constructor method

Tags: javascript, object, methods

How can i use this method from my own project/design

```
Github.prototype.handleErr = function(res) {
  if(!res.ok) {
   throw new Error('Something went wrong!!' + res.status);
  }

  return res;
 }
```

Inside another method but the same object

```
const git = new Github();

Github.prototype.getUser = (user) => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Profile
    fetch(something)
    .then(this.handleErr)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => resolve(data))
    .catch(err => reject(err));
})
```

}

it didn't work with this.handleErr

i wanted to make a fetch request and use the `git.handleErr()` function inside `.then()` consumer, before handling the data response.

Comment: What have you tried and what is the exact issue you're encountering? It's not really clear what you expect this code to do or why your expectations were not met. I think more context would really help clarify what it is you are asking.

Comment: I edited now, hope is clear enough.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ES6 arrow functions not working on the prototype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31755186/es6-arrow-functions-not-working-on-the-prototype)

Comment: Look again i added the whole script

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i figured out. I modified the arrow function syntax

`Github.prototype.getUser = (user) => {}`

to the normal syntax

`Github.prototype.getUser = function(user) {}`

Acording to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31755186/es6-arrow-functions-not-working-on-the-prototype) it was referred as a global/undefined `this.` so that's why it didn't work in the first instance. Thank you [str](https://stackoverflow.com/users/906113/str).